# Cannot open projects with android studio

Tags: android, sdk

I am trying to open some projects which shows how to use RSS feed with android. Every time I am trying to open I get this error:

> Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-8'

I tried to install API 8 via SDK Manager but API 8 shows as not compatible with windows.. How can I run the project without having that API 8?

**build.gradle**

> // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
>   to all sub-projects/modules. buildscript {
>
> ```
> repositories {
>     jcenter()
> }
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
>   } 
> }
>
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>        jcenter()
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: change the minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion in app's build.gradle file.

Comment: will not work, it will come up with `Error:(4, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'minSdkVersion()'`

Comment: Please paste your build.gradle file. App level.

Comment: I will add to the question

Comment: Not the top level, the app level.

Comment: Oh me..So that's where the problems hide.. @drulabs thanks for pointing me on the right way. I was looking at the top lvl gradle but then I opened appication folder and yet, still was looking at the top lvl gradle until I had to open another app folder. Thanks for this! :D